# inside the function "bigger()", it has returned a value--a or b. so, why do still need "return"s before "bigger()"s in the function "median()"?

Tags: python, return

inside the function "bigger()", it has returned a value--a or b. 
so, why do still need "return"s before "bigger()"s in the function "median()"?
Here is the code:

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    else:
        return b

def biggest(a,b,c):
    return bigger(a,bigger(b,c))

def median(a,b,c):   
    if a == biggest(a,b,c):
        return bigger(b,c)     #the function "bigger()" above has returned a value,
                           #so, why still need a 'return' before bigger(b,c)?
    elif b == biggest(a,b,c):
        return bigger(a,c)
    else:
        return bigger(a,b)
```

Comment: Because each function returns the value to the caller. The caller is free to do whatever he wishes with the value, including returning it to its caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain with examples, maybe it is simpler.

You have defined your `bigger` function, that returns a value, right?

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

Now, you have defined a `biggest` function, and you are calling `bigger` from that function.

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    return bigger(a,bigger(b,c))
```

Now imagine the thousands of stuff that you could do with the value returned from `bigger`.

You could use the **returned value** from `bigger` anywhere within `biggest` function. For example:

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    some_var = bigger(a,bigger(b,c))
    return some_var + 10
```

Or

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    list_of_values = []
    list_of_values.append(bigger(a,bigger(b,c)))
```

But as you wish to use the value returned from `bigger` in the function that calls `biggest` , you should return that again so that the caller of `biggest` gets this value. Otherwise, it would get `None` which basically tells the caller "No value returned."

Answer (score 0):

A function call is an expression. Consider the following:

```
def add(a, b):
    a + b

x = add(3, 5)
```

Would you expect `x` to now have the value `8`? You shouldn't because `add` did not return the value of the expression `a+b`. The correct definition would be

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Now consider this function:

```
def backwards_add(a, b):
    add(b, a)

x = backwards_add(3, 5)
```

Again, would you expect that `x` has the value `8`? Once again, you shouldn't because `backwards_add` did not return the value of the expression `add(b, a)`. The correct definition is

```
def backwards_add(a, b):
    return add(b, a)
```

There are some languages that implicitly return the value of the last expression executed in a function (cf. Perl

```
sub add {
    $1 + $2;
}
my $x = add(3, 5);  # x has the value 8
```

), but Python is not one of those languages. You must explicitly return a value, or it will return `None` for you.